# Convert string representation of an array of int to a groovy list

Tags: groovy

If I am given an string which is the repsentation of an array of int like below

`String d = "[2,3,4,5]"`

How I convert to an array of string?

`String[] f = convert d to array of String`

Also how I convert to an array of int?

```
int[] f = convert d to array of int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Eval.me` like so:

```
String[] f = Eval.me( d )*.toString()
```

Or

```
int[] i = Eval.me( d )
```

Be careful though, as if this String is entered by a third party, it could do nasty things and is a huge security risk...  To get round that, you'd need to parse it yourself with something like:

```
def simplisticParse( String input, Class requiredType ) {
  input.dropWhile { it != '[' }
       .drop( 1 )
       .takeWhile { it != ']' }
       .split( ',' )*.asType( requiredType )
}

String[] s = simplisticParse( d, String )
int[] i = simplisticParse( d, Integer )
```

Comment: Also should be noted that you say _"groovy list"_ in the question title, but those are arrays, change `String[]` or `int[]` to `List` and you'll have a List of objects instead :-)

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for other solutions, since my values contained strings including dots in them and [found this](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/How-to-convert-String-quot-1-2-3-quot-to-List-td4500137.html#a4502203).

This code should work for you:

```
"[1,2,3]".tokenize(',[]')*.toInteger()
```